# What is the difference between bitwise and logical operators inside conditional statements in C?

Tags: c, conditional-statements, bitwise-operators, logical-operators

There are many questions on the net that refer to the differences between bitwise and logical operators. Hoping that I have done a good search, none of them specialize to whether they are the same or not when used inside conditional statements nor refer exclusively to C Language. The majority referred to C++ and C# and I do not know if the same answers were applicable to C Language too.

This is an example code I wrote to test what is going on:

```
// Difference between logical && and bitwise & //

#include <stdio.h>

#define TRUE 123>45
#define FALSE 4>2342

void print_tt(int table[][4]);

int main(void) {

    int and_tt[2][4];   // AND truth table
    int or_tt[2][4];    // OR truth table

    // Create truth table for logical and bitwise AND operator all in one 2d array
    and_tt[0][0] = TRUE && TRUE ? 1 : 0;
    and_tt[0][1] = TRUE && FALSE ? 1 : 0;
    and_tt[0][2] = FALSE && TRUE ? 1 : 0;
    and_tt[0][3] = FALSE && FALSE ? 1 : 0;
    and_tt[1][0] = TRUE & TRUE ? 1 : 0;
    and_tt[1][1] = TRUE & FALSE ? 1 : 0;
    and_tt[1][2] = FALSE & TRUE ? 1 : 0;
    and_tt[1][3] = FALSE & FALSE ? 1 : 0;

    // Create truth table for logical and bitwise OR operator all in one 2d array
    or_tt[0][0] = TRUE || TRUE ? 1 : 0;
    or_tt[0][1] = TRUE || FALSE ? 1 : 0;
    or_tt[0][2] = FALSE || TRUE ? 1 : 0;
    or_tt[0][3] = FALSE || FALSE ? 1 : 0;
    or_tt[1][0] = TRUE | TRUE ? 1 : 0;
    or_tt[1][1] = TRUE | FALSE ? 1 : 0;
    or_tt[1][2] = FALSE | TRUE ? 1 : 0;
    or_tt[1][3] = FALSE | FALSE ? 1 : 0;

    puts("_______AND_______");
    puts("Logical   Bitwise");
    print_tt(and_tt);

    puts("_______OR________");
    puts("Logical   Bitwise");
    print_tt(or_tt);

}


// prints the truth table of the bitwise and logical operator given side by side
void print_tt(int table[][4]) {
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<4 ; ++i) {
        printf("%-10s%s\n", table[0][i] ? "true" : "false",
            table[1][i] ? "true" : "false");
    }
}
```

The program’s output is:

```
_______AND_______
Logical   Bitwise
true      true
false     false
false     false
false     false
_______OR________
Logical   Bitwise
true      true
true      true
true      true
false     false
```

Which proves that there are no differences between bitwise and logical operators. Changing the definition of `TRUE` and `FALSE` macros to include the remaining comparison operators, one can see that there is no difference again.

Therefore, if there are differences, these might be associated to the way the compiler interprets the statement or the efficiency of the code.

In conclusion, in the specific case when we have a bitwise or logical operator between two or more results of a comparison operation inside a conditional statement, which of the two should we use, mostly for greater efficiency ?

Comment: You have a logic error in your proof :-) You have shown that there is no difference in one set of cases and incorrectly extrapolated that to be true for all cases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're only checking the values `0` and `1`. Try **other values** and you'll see differences.

```
int a = 4, b = 2;

puts(a && b ? "true" : "false");
puts(a & b  ? "true" : "false");
```

This prints:

```
true
false
```

Bitwise operators **only work with integers**. Logical operators can be used with pointers, floating point numbers, and other non-integral types.

There's also **short-circuiting**. The logical operators won't evaluate their second operand if the first was enough.

```
int a() { puts("a"); return 0; }
int b() { puts("b"); return 1; }

int main() {
    puts(a() && b() ? "true" : "false");
    puts("---");
    puts(a() & b()  ? "true" : "false");
}
```

This prints:

```
a
false
---
a
b
false
```

Notice how `b` is printed when using `&`. There is no short-circuiting so `&` calls both functions, whereas `&&` only calls `a()`.

And on a subtler note, unlike `&&`, `&` does not impose an **order of evaluation** on its operands. The output could equally well have the `a` and `b` printouts reversed.

```
a
false
---
b
a
false
```

If you put *all of these differences aside*, then yes, the operators are equivalent. In that case, **do not worry about efficiency**. Use whichever operators are semantically correct: the logical ones.

(If it helps ease your mind, there will be no difference in efficiency. Compilers are very smart and will certainly emit the optimal bytecode to evaluate these expressions, whichever operator you use.)

Comment: Also short circuiting.

Comment: I am aware of this difference but the one that my question is not explicitly referring to is in the case when we have a bitwise or logical operator between two or more results of a comparison operation inside a conditional statement.

Comment: I have also seen all this information you posted scattered in many different websites but all of them referred to either C++ or C#. Now I also know that the same thing goes for C and everything is gathered in one place.

Answer (score 2):

```
1101 & 0010 = 0000, 1101 && 0010 = True
1101 | 0010 = 1111, 1101 || 0010 = True
```

The reason is bitwise compares each bit separately whereas logical treats the whole bit string as one bit true or false. When looking at a bit string of one bit there is indeed no difference between logical and bitwise operators. Another way of thinking of it is bitwise operators are functions from integers to integers where logical operators are functions from booleans to booleans.

By calling `table[0][i] ? "true" : "false"` you are casting the integer into a bit. If you keep it as an integer you will see the difference between the two types of operators.

Comment: You mean that, the output of 123>45 is a one bit string which is 0x1 ?

Comment: No it is implementation dependent. but when you print you are casting to the string true or false. If you just printed the values as integers instead of casting to bools you will see the difference.

Comment: @pgmank: `&&` implicitly casts both sides to `bool` first (at least that's how C++ defines it, I didn't check C.  Modern C may define it in terms of `_Bool`).  Many implementations define `bool` as a 1-byte integer that's all zero except for the low bit being either 0 or 1, but other definitions are possible and the C abstract machine doesn't care, it defines `&&` in terms of the value semantics of `bool`.  It would be equivalent to talk about comparisons producing a 0 or 1 integer, so `x && y` is still equivalent to `x != 0 && y != 0`.

Answer (score 2):

`&&` is a boolean operator, while `&` is a bitwise operator.

`&` is an **and** operation on two integers. Example: `1100 & 1001 = 1101`, so `12 & 9 = 13`.

`&&` only checks if both (left and right) values are TRUE (i.e. non-zero).

`1 & 2` for example is `0`, because a binary and of 1 and 2 is 0. Example: `01 & 10 = 00`

While `1 && 2` is like `TRUE && TRUE`, which also equals true. So with `&&`, both left and right values are "converted" to a boolean expression first and are then compared.

Also, don't forget that compilers are capable of short circuiting `&&` expressions. Like this one:

```
bool variable = isValid && compareSomething()
```

The right value is not evaluated, because it doesn't need to. The first one already states clearly that `variable` is `isValid`, as long as `isValid` is true.

[Read more](http://web.student.tuwien.ac.at/~e0226430/tutorial/operators.xhtml)